# Twitter Streaming api Oauth - 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to use Oauth with the Twitter Streaming API but I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error.

Authorization header used - OAuth oauth_consumer_key=consumer key, oauth_nonce=nonce, oauth_signature=signature, oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp=timestamp, oauth_token=auth_token, oauth_version="1.0"

each key/value pair percent encoded as per [twitter oauth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests)

But still getting 401 unauthorize error.
Can anyone please help resolve this?

Comment: What platform are you working with? If iOS/macOS, I can help.

Comment: Hi, I need help with same issue on iOS. @Supertecnoboff